# Give element its default margin through inline-style

Tags: html, css

In my external CSS file, I am setting the style of all `<h3>` elements to `margin-bottom: 0;`

How would I do an inline-style to give a certain `<h3>` element its default margin back? The following code does not give a `<h3>` element its default margin.

```css
h3 {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<h3>This has no margin.</h3>
<h3 style="margin-bottom: auto;">This should have it's default margin.</h3>
```

Comment: What about `h3 {margin-bottom: initial}` ?

Comment: @d_z90 What will that do?

Comment: It resets it to the default value. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/initial

Comment: Default margin can be different in different browsers so better to explicitly add some value.

Comment: `margin-bottom: inherit;` should also do the work.

Comment: @skobaljic Sadly not

Comment: Correct, it would inherit from parent.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of inlining css you could add a specific class and use the [not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nothttp://) css selector on the element you don't want to target:

```
h3:not(.noborder) {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

<h3>This has no margin.</h3>
<h3 class="noborder">This should have it's default margin.</h3>
```

Comment: I could do this but I was really hoping for an inline-style

Comment: the problem is that you don't know from where you are inheriting, to track that you could probably use JS but it seems overkill

Answer (score -1):

You can reset  the value via the keyword `initial`.
Read more about it here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_initial.asp

Comment: I tried `<h3 style="margin-bottom: initial;">` but it doesn't give the bottom margin back.